# Deallocation of controller instantiated using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I am instantiating a viewcontroller using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. Do I have to expect it to be completely released when I assigned **nil** to VC variable in ARC setup or storyboard would retain it anyway?

I am presenting viewcontroller modally using presentViewController, then inside vc dismissing it. However, I don't see `dealloc` method of vc is being called.

Update:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL];
RViewControllerEx *viewController = (RViewControllerEx *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SB_RDVC"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

- I have NSLog in -dealloc method to determine it's called or not
- I'm using local variable and it's not deallocating immediately

Comment: No, the storyboard does not keep a reference to your controller. If you dismiss it, and don't have any strong references yourself, it should be deallocated after the dismissal animation is complete.

Comment: @rdelmar is it possible something within that viewcontroller holds itself from releasing? For example retaining self more than required, etc..

Comment: Do you have any timers running, or any other long running precesses?

Comment: Well, that part is out of the code I am managing, but I noticed there are timers, dispatch queues.

Comment: Timers retain their target, so if you have timers running with repeats, then that will cause the controller to be retained. You could invalidate any timers on viewDidDisappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information. Are you using ARC? Are you using a local variable to hold a pointer to the VC, or an instance variable?

How are you concluding that the modal VC's dealloc isn't being called?

If you instantiate your VC using a strong local variable and then call presentViewcontroller:animated:completion:, the presenting view controller will keep a strong reference to your VC while it is being displayed. (You need to use a strong local variable or the newly created VC will be deallocated as soon as you create it.

As soon as the modal is done being dismissed, the presenting view controller will clear it's strong reference, and the modal should be deallocated.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ARC. Please see updated question. I only suspect `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` is retaining my VC, but not sure how to check easily.

Comment: No, `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` would return an autoreleased object. The `presentViewcontroller:animated:completion:` method would keep a strong reference to your view controller.

Comment: @Duncan So does it that get released when the view is dismissed?

Comment: Yes, if you don't have any strong references to it. You really need to read up on ARC memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Dealloc is not called right away. With ARC the system will automatically clean up views that are no longer being used when it needs to.

In your case, once the view is dismissed, it will hang around until the system needs the space.

Depending on what you are attempting/ need to do in the dealloc there are a few solutions (post your needs if interested)

Comment: It's called immediately for all of viewcontrollers in my project.

Comment: I could be wrong, but like I said I believe and in my experience that is not always the case. If there is something you need to do a soon as the view is dismissed there are options for that. but if not I believe you can just let ARC do its thing.

Comment: Each time I present my viewcontroller, allocated memory is always increasing and never decreasing to hundred megabytes. I'm sure dealloc should be called in my case.

Comment: So post your code, along with the parts of the .h file that declare the instance variables/properties you are using to save a reference to this VC.